# Failed Test Payment does not call client-side javascript callback in new local currency payment system(local currency breaking change)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, local, payment, currency

I am transferring our game to the new local currency payment system.
It works fine for successful test payments however when I wanted to test a failed payment with a test user it does not behave like I expected it to.

According to the Facebook documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/fulfillment/#jscallback) it will send a javascript object that looks something like this:

```
{ 
  "payment_id": 375225169259274, 
  "quantity": 1, 
  "status": "completed", 
  "signed_request": "bjyedxDDlRj..." 
}
```

When I test the payment with the setting **always succeed**, this javascript object is sent.
However, when I test the payment with the setting **always fail**, this javascript object is not sent.

The Facebook payment dialog shows: "*This is an expected failure from a test credential*." and I also receive the realtime update on the server but the payment dialog stays open with the options to **Retry** and **Cancel**.
When I click cancel, the game only receives a javascript object with the error code for user canceling but not one of a failed payment.

The Facebook documentation specifically states that

> The status of the order returned from the JS callback can be
>   **initiated**, **completed** or **failed**. Developers should fulfill the order
>   only if the status is  completed. If you see a status of initiated,
>   this indicates a payment that has not yet completed. You should
>   display a message to the user to let them know that the payment is
>   pending, and the order will be fulfilled once the payment completes.

So I am assuming I should get a javascript object with `"status":"failed"` when a payment failed.

Does anybody got the same problem? Does anyone know how to know client-side if a payment failed? Is this just a problem for test payments?

Comment: Same for me as of today (